# display none breaks animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

i want a certain div to be shown in certain circumstances, and i want it to be animated, at the start it should be invisible so...

```
.fixedNav{
    background-color: rgba(28,20,13, 0.75);
    position:fixed;
    color:white;
    width:60vw;
    margin-top:-50px !important;
    z-index: 1;
    display:none;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity .3s ease-in;
}
```

and then i animate the opacity with css by adding this class, with jquery, to it:

```
.fixedNavActive{
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
}
```

and it all works fine if i remove the display: none; from the main class, if i leave it there then the opacity isn't animated, it just appears, why does it break it and how can i make it animate the opacity instead of toggling it to 1?

Comment: Perhaps you should hava look at jQuery's fadeIn, and fadeOut. Probably makes it a lot less complicated...

Comment: that is plan b, however i would like it to be implemented in css, as it seems it's less "laggy"

Comment: `display` can't be animated.

Comment: Is fixedNav a div element?

Comment: if you could recheck the code, you will see that i don't animate display, i animate opacity, display is used to make sure that the element is not clickable/visible/or available in any kind of form to the user.

Comment: Perhaps you should ook at an alternative for the display: none. Opacity or visibility might get you in the right direction but they behave different than display. CSS transitions indeed work "smoother" but seem to be less powerfull when it comes down certain scenarios's.

Comment: This might help: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you cannot animate display properties, and even though you're only trying to animate the `opacity`, that transition fails because when the transition begins, the element doesn't exist. It has been removed from the flow due to the `display: none` property.

You can achieve the effect you're looking for by using `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`, which is an animatable property, and if you need to effectively remove the element from the flow when it lacks visibility, then you can apply a `max-height` of `1px` to the element and a `margin-top` of `-1px`.

Comment: Visibility is only animatable as far as delay functions. It only has two states **on/off**, there is no intermediate step.

Comment: That seems irrelevant to his/her case. He/she needs the visibility property to change instantaneously, and then the opacity animation can begin once the visibility property has changed.

Comment: Which is my point....you have to stagger the two: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

Comment: Okay, now it makes sense =) thank you, i ended up using visibility and opacity, which works marvellously

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hGe43/1/)

`display` properties can not be animated in CSS.

You can just use `opacity:0;` and then `opacity:1`.

To get a better effect you could always use `visibility:hidden;` for your use.

Answer (score 0):

I place the 'display:none;' on the content of the element, or wrap what I want to hide in another div. And then set the transition on the surrounding element.
To let the animation fade both in and out you will have to set the height, padding or something to keep it from getting a height of 0 the second the content disappears.

Solves it for me at least :)

```css
.hidden { 
    opacity: 1;
    height:20px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.container:hover > .hidden{
   opacity: 0;
   height:0;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.container:hover > .hidden > .hidden-content{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div> Hello! </div> 
  <div class="hidden">
      <div class="hidden-content"> Goodbye! </div>
   </div>  
  <div> Some other text! </div>
</div>
```